# I have a table having duplicate names but different marks, need output as below

Tags: sql, string-concatenation

I have an input table tabl1

tab1

```
name    marks    
rb     34      
km     434     
rn     343     
sm     343     
sm     545     
rb     33      
km     22      
jl     234
```

Require output as
output

```
name    marks       
jl      234         
km      434,22      
rb      34,33       
rn      343         
sm      343,545
```

Comment: Please tag the RDBMS that you are using along with its version. E.g `Oracle11g`, `SQL Server 2019` etc.,

Comment: which database do you use

Comment: This was asked in an interview, and interviewed wanted a SQL query for this question.

Comment: @EktaJ arn't this kinda against the rule of **"interview"**, unless they told you looking for help is ok.

Comment: @T.Peter Not really! As this interview process got over yesterday. :)

Comment: Still, which dbms were you supposed to give an answer for?

Answer (score 2):

please be specific on the database you were asked for! Given you did not share enough information on which database to use, I can only give an example of different SQL syntax. Below is a summary I did for different databases.

### MySQL

use group_concat to form new groups

```sql
select  name, group_concat(marks)
    from test
    group by name
```

### SQL Server

you need to convert `marks` to string type first before concatenating them, use `name` as the join key.

```sql
    SELECT DISTINCT 
       name,
       Stuff((SELECT ', ' + cast(marks as varchar)
              FROM   test t2 
              WHERE  t2.name  = t1.name  
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') marks
FROM   test t1
```

### SQL Server 2017 and later

there is a function string_agg which you can specify a delimiter to group the rows

```sql
select  name, string_agg(marks, ',')
    from test
    group by name
```

### Postgres 9.3+

```sql
SELECT  name,
        array_agg(marks) as marks
FROM test
GROUP BY name
```

Answer (score 0):

In oracle, you can use `listagg` and group by as follows:

```
Select name,
       Listagg(marks,',') within group (order by marks) as marks
  From your_tablr
Group by name
```

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres you would use `string_agg()`

```
select name, string_agg(marks::text, ',') as marks
from the_table
group by name
order by name;
```